# Node-Red Uploaded image gets corrupted

Tags: image, upload, node-red

I have a Node-RED flow to upload an image and save it to a file. But the image gets corrupted on upload/save. I tested to change the file via file explorer and my server showed my image perfectly. So the problem is the upload section and when i download the uploaded picture my windows photos shows me that the "file type is probably not supported".

[image: Flow Image]

My flow:

```
[{"id":"b561f39b.7a55c","type":"ui_upload","z":"85326e02.d8e2b","group":"e12d112e.2bd9c","title":"Hallenplan (PNG, 1280x600)","name":"","order":3,"width":0,"height":5,"chunk":"256","transfer":"binary","x":130,"y":380,"wires":[["7f8ff192.87745"]]},{"id":"7f8ff192.87745","type":"file","z":"85326e02.d8e2b","name":"","filename":"/tmp/hallenplan.png","appendNewline":false,"createDir":false,"overwriteFile":"true","encoding":"binary","x":550,"y":380,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"8f232064.9538","type":"http in","z":"85326e02.d8e2b","name":"","url":"/img/hallenplan.png","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":170,"y":440,"wires":[["96426e36.186fb"]]},{"id":"96426e36.186fb","type":"file in","z":"85326e02.d8e2b","name":"","filename":"/tmp/hallenplan.png","format":"","x":400,"y":440,"wires":[["a62d44b7.b91498"]]},{"id":"751ec35b.adf85c","type":"http response","z":"85326e02.d8e2b","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":770,"y":440,"wires":[]},{"id":"a62d44b7.b91498","type":"change","z":"85326e02.d8e2b","name":"Set Headers","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"headers","pt":"msg","to":"{}","tot":"json"},{"t":"set","p":"headers.content-type","pt":"msg","to":"image/png","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":590,"y":440,"wires":[["751ec35b.adf85c"]]},{"id":"e12d112e.2bd9c","type":"ui_group","name":"Upload","tab":"acda14fc.fcb598","order":2,"disp":true,"width":"12","collapse":false},{"id":"acda14fc.fcb598","type":"ui_tab","name":"Timo_Burkhardt","icon":"dashboard","disabled":false,"hidden":false}]
```

Comment: You need to add more details to the text, and not just expect people to import a random flow. Explain what nodes you are actually using.

Comment: i added an image.

Comment: You still need to add more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full flow for repeatedly uploading png images of any size (that fits in memory) to `/tmp/image.png`.

[image]

How it works:

- get image chunks uploaded with node ui_upload
- set `type` to `buffer` since ui_node sets the default `type` as `string`
- join chunks to a blob in memory
- save blob to file by overwriting an existing file

The flow code:

```
[{"id":"87b7f497.057208","type":"file","z":"8130dbcf.fc6768","name":"","filename":"/tmp/image.png","appendNewline":false,"createDir":false,"overwriteFile":"true","encoding":"setbymsg","x":640,"y":220,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"b4191d57.653ad8","type":"join","z":"8130dbcf.fc6768","name":"","mode":"auto","build":"string","property":"payload","propertyType":"msg","key":"topic","joiner":"\\n","joinerType":"str","accumulate":"false","timeout":"","count":"","reduceRight":false,"x":470,"y":220,"wires":[["87b7f497.057208"]]},{"id":"584ef1f0.f312e8","type":"change","z":"8130dbcf.fc6768","name":"Set type=buffer","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"parts.type","pt":"msg","to":"buffer","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":300,"y":220,"wires":[["b4191d57.653ad8"]]},{"id":"86a479d3.e5fd6","type":"ui_upload","z":"8130dbcf.fc6768","group":"ca0d541e.2985e","title":"upload2","name":"","order":1,"width":0,"height":5,"chunk":256,"transfer":"binary","x":130,"y":220,"wires":[["584ef1f0.f312e8"]]},{"id":"ca0d541e.2985e","type":"ui_group","name":"Konfiguration","tab":"b75d261a.ea0aa8","order":1,"disp":true,"width":"6","collapse":false},{"id":"b75d261a.ea0aa8","type":"ui_tab","name":"Floorplan","icon":"dashboard","disabled":false,"hidden":false}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the ui-upload node breaks the uploaded file up into 256kb chunks.

You have then set the file-out node to overwrite the file on each incoming message, this means that the file written to disk only contains the last chunk of the image you upload (a maximum of 256kb).

The quick possible solution may be to insert a join node between the ui-upload and the file node to reassemble the upload into a single message. But I'm not sure that will work as I think it will not output a buffer as the consolidated payload (because the ui-upload node is setting the type to be "string").

Comment: I added a join between but the upload does not work either. 

But your explanation sounds good i will try more

Comment: The nasty hack is to put a change node between the ui-upload and the join node to change `msg.parts.type` from `string` to `buffer`

Comment: I did that but it wont work either 
https://imgur.com/lZeYhGX

Is that right?

Comment: No, it should be the word `buffer`, but it still might not work